# Array of link list

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm having trouble while implementing array of link list in c++. I made 2 functions , one insert and display. Can someone help ?

This is the main function

```
node* a[100],*b,*temp,*temp2;
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{

    a[i]=NULL;;
}

insert_node(a,1,143);
display(a,1)
```

And this is insert function

```
void insert_node(node **q[100],int pos,int data)
{
node *temp,*temp2;
if(*q[pos]==NULL)
{
    temp=new node;
    temp->next=NULL;
   temp->data=data;
   *q[pos]=temp;
}
else
{
    temp2=*q[pos];
    while(temp2->next != NULL )
    {
        temp2=*q[pos];
        temp2=temp2->next;
    }
    temp=new node;
    temp->next=NULL;
    temp->data=data;
    temp2->next=temp;
}
}
```

and this is display function

```
void display(node **q[100], int pos)
{
node * temp;

temp=*q[pos];
cout<<"\n";
while(temp->next != NULL)
{
    cout<<" "<<temp->data;
}
}
```

It gives error that

```
error: cannot convert 'node**' to 'node***' for argument '1' to 'void insert_node(node***, int, int)'

error: cannot convert 'node**' to 'node***' for argument '1' to 'void display(node***, int)
```

Comment: In C++ there is rarely a reason to be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Comment: Whichever book you're reading to learn C++, get rid of it and start reading a different book.

Comment: In the arguments to your functions, you have node** q[100], which is a triple pointer. What you want is either node **q or node *q[100].

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I didn't read any book. Can you suggest one to clear all basics out ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Ujjwalchhabra You want an array of a linked list?  Simple:  `std::array<std::list<node>, 100> my_array_of_linked_list;`.  An array of 100 linked list that stores `node` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
void insert_node(node **q[100],int pos,int data)
```

to

```
void insert_node(node *q[100],int pos,int data)
```

and

```
void display(node **q[100], int pos)
```

to

```
void display(node *q[100], int pos)
```

Comment: Okay I had to also remove all the de-references and it worked. But can you explain why we changed so ? Don't we need a pointer to pointer while receiving a pointer ?

**EDIT : Okay I get it. Thanks a ton :D**